# What does a colon in makefile dependencies list means?

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

I'm working on a project using makefile. Some of the make rules have the following format:

```
a.o b.o c.o : %.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

What's the meaning of such a rule? I'm unable to find explanation in the official manual, but I guess it's used for applying pattern-matching on only the *.o files listed as targets. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the GNU Make,

> [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).
>
> Static pattern rules are rules which specify multiple targets and
>   construct the prerequisite names for each target based on the target
>   name. They are more general than ordinary rules with multiple targets
>   because the targets do not have to have identical prerequisites. Their
>   prerequisites must be analogous, but not necessarily identical.

The syntax for static pattern rules:

```
targets : target-pattern: prereq-patterns …
        recipe
        …
```

---

Pattern rule is mentioned as % in the target. It matches any target ends with `.o` here `a.o`, `b.o` and `c.o`.

Here ‘`$<’` is the automatic variable that holds the name of the prerequisite and ‘`$@’` is the automatic variable that holds the name of the target.

```
a.o b.o c.o : %.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```